# Upload images with Vue.js using events not working due to component issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to upload images with this [plugin](https://vuejsexamples.com/a-simple-upload-multiple-image-component-for-vuejs/), but unfortunately my `uploadImageSuccess` event is not firing. Really sorry if wrong because I'm new to Vue.js.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>vue-upload-multiple-image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="el">
            <div id="my-strictly-unique-vue-upload-multiple-image" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
                <vue-upload-multiple-image
                    @upload-success="uploadImageSuccess"
                    @before-remove="beforeRemove"
                    @edit-image="editImage"
                    @data-change="dataChange"
                    :data-images="images"
                    ></vue-upload-multiple-image>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-upload-multiple-image@1.0.2/dist/vue-upload-multiple-image.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var vm = new Vue({
                el: '#el',
                data() {
                    return {
                        images: []
                    }
                },
                components: {
                    VueUploadMultipleImage
                },
                methods: {
                    uploadImageSuccess(formData, index, fileList) {
                        alert('dd');
                        console.log('data', formData, index, fileList)
                        // Upload image api
                        // axios.post('http://your-url-upload', { data: formData }).then(response => {
                        //   console.log(response)
                        // })
                    },
                    beforeRemove(index, done, fileList) {
                        console.log('index', index, fileList)
                        var r = confirm("remove image")
                        if (r == true) {
                            done()
                        } else {
                        }
                    },
                    editImage(formData, index, fileList) {
                        console.log('edit data', formData, index, fileList)
                    },
                    dataChange(data) {
                        console.log(data)
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It would be great if someone can help. I get this error:

> ReferenceError: VueUploadMultipleImage is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing the plugin using a CDN site (i.e.: `https://unpkg.com/vue-upload-multiple-image@1.0.2/dist/vue-upload-multiple-image.js`). So, it will be directly (and globally) available in your DOM. For this reason you **do not need to mount** `VueUploadMultipleImage` using the following:

```
 components: {
      VueUploadMultipleImage
 },
```

Then, by removing the above mentioned snippet you'd get rid of the `ReferenceError`.

---

For the sake of completeness, please mind that the above snippet is required only if you use the plugin through NPM. In that specific case you should first import the plugin:

```
import VueUploadMultipleImage from 'vue-upload-multiple-image'
```

and then mount it using:

```
  components: {
    VueUploadMultipleImage,
  },
```

Hope it helps!